# Excel 2010 pick a time

Tags: excel-2010, timepicker

is there any way in excel that would allow me to pick a specific time in a format HH:MM. The
Date and Time picker allows to select only Calendar Day.

Desired result would be something like

[Rad Time Picker](http://www.google.at/imgres?biw=1536&bih=828&tbm=isch&tbnid=u1QgJDIPkiM6XM%3a&imgrefurl=http://blogs.telerik.com/telerikmarketing/posts/12-02-14/pick-your-time-with-radtimepicker-for-winforms.aspx&docid=KVAACLUfM42uyM&imgurl=http://blogs.telerik.com/images/default-source/metablog/Q1_2012_WF_TimePicker.png%253Fsfvrsn%253D0&w=312&h=275&ei=ZHDyUYaFOcqFtAamvIGwAg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:14,s:0,i:121&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=184&tbnw=208&start=0&ndsp=24&tx=126&ty=50)

with a 1 minute sequence

Answer (score 1):

You could set up 2 cells (one for hour, one for minutes), and set up corresponding spin buttons and have each cycle through the hours and minutes as you desire. then a button to grab the result and place it where you want.

Info on adding a spin button [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-scroll-bar-or-spin-button-to-a-worksheet-HP010236682.aspx#BMadd_or_edit_a_spin_button_%28control_to)